# AAD authentication fails in IE in iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a page with a iframe that shows a corporate site authenticated by AAD SSO.

When I visit the corporate site directly in IE, everything is ok, but when it is in iframe, it redirects to login.microsoft.com, then back and I get error:

```
Forbidden: 

This corporate app can't be accessed.
You are not authorized to access this application
Azure AD Application Proxy 


Azure AD Application Proxy 

Status code:  Forbidden 

Url:  https://mycorporatesite/%3ferror%3daccess_denied%26error_description%3dAADSTS50105%253a%2bThe%2bsigned%2bin%2buser%2b%2527%2... 

 TransactionID:  2656c424-9b94-4af7-8ed3-123b65b6fef9 

 ConnectorGroupId:  b58ad765-2dc9-443e-bed8-70558cc3f463 

 Timestamp:  5/20/2019 7:26:57 AM
```

It works in all browsers including Edge except IE (even inPrivate mode)

I have to mention, that my PC is connected to different AD that the one used by the site, but as I mentioned, it works fine when I visit the site directly.

Here are request being made by the iframe:

```
GET https://mycorporatesite.com/RestApi/?SPHostUrl=.....
Response 302 / Found
Response Headers: location: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...

GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...
Response 302 / Found
Response Headers: location: https://mycorporatesite.com?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS50105%3a+The+signed+in+user+%27%7bEmailHidden%7d%27+is+not+assigned+to+a+role+for+the+application+...

GET https://mycorporatesite.com?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS50105%3a+The+signed+in+user+%27%7bEmailHidden%7d%27+is+not+assigned+to+a+role+for+the+application+...
Response 403 / Forbidden
```

Comment: This error can happen either when the user is not assigned to the application in Azure Active Directory, or if on the backend the user does not have permission to access the application. Please refer these links to get more information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-sign-in-bad-gateway-timeout-error and https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-troubleshoot.md

Comment: Can you include the part of the error that mentions the correlation ID and timestamp?

Comment: @deepak-MSFT - I understand the error, but it shouldn't occur, because I'm able to access the site directly. Why it is happening in iframe? I guess iframe is picking wrong user

Comment: Try to print the user related information from the Iframe to check which user it is using may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I've edited anwser to include all error details, but there's only transaction id, timestamp and ConnectorGroupId. I'm almost sure that IE IFrame uses my account conntected to Windows.

Comment: Try to add your site in trusted site site zone also try to add your AAD login page to trusted site zone and again try to test the issue. It is not recommended to display AAD login page inside an iframe. It may create this kind of issues.

Comment: Try to add your site in trusted site site zone also try to add your AAD login page to trusted site zone and again try to test the issue. It is not recommended to display AAD login page inside an iframe. It may create this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be related to the browser. Is it possible that in the other browsers you were signed in to Azure AD with a different user?

The error message you see is returned when the application requires users to be assigned to the app, but the signed-in user is not assigned.

Comment: No, this is not the case. As I said, I'm able to visit the page directly in the same browser in the same window in the same session, so I'm signed with correct user.

Comment: @Liero Is the user identified in the error message (when in iframe) the same user that is signed in when you go to the site in the full frame?

Comment: well, I don't know what user is used by iframe, but I guess its different user - the one from windows. I dont know how to find out